# Error de foreign keys creando base de datos

Tags: mysql

Al ejecutar el código, me sale el siguiente error, que por lo que he visto tiene que ver con las foreign key de la tabla factura:
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'libreria.new_table' (errno: 150)

Las tablas son: vendedor, cliente y factura. Vendedor y cliente tienen de clave primaria nombre y apellidos

Las tablas las creé usando el workbench y no encuentro el fallo.También he probado a cambiar el delete y el update a cascade pero creo que en este caso no tiene nada que ver.

El código es el siguiente:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `libreria` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `libreria` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `libreria` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Cliente`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libreria`.`Cliente` (
  `nombre` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `edad` INT NOT NULL,
  `genero` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (nombre, apellidos))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Vendedor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libreria`.`Vendedor` (
  `nombre` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `salario` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `fecha_contratacion` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (nombre, apellidos))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Factura`
-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `libreria`.`Factura` (
  `cod_factura` INT NOT NULL,
  `fecha` DATE NOT NULL,
  `nombre_cliente` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos_cliente` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_vendedor` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos_vendedor` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cod_factura`),
  INDEX `nombre_cliente_idx` (`nombre_cliente` ASC),
  INDEX `apellidos_cliente_idx` (`apellidos_cliente` ASC),
  INDEX `nombre_vendedor_idx` (`nombre_vendedor` ASC),
  INDEX `apellidos_vendedor_idx` (`apellidos_vendedor` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `nombre_cliente`
    FOREIGN KEY (`nombre_cliente`)
    REFERENCES `libreria`.`cliente` (`nombre`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `apellidos_cliente`
    FOREIGN KEY (`apellidos_cliente`)
    REFERENCES `libreria`.`cliente` (`apellidos`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `nombre_vendedor`
    FOREIGN KEY (`nombre_vendedor`)
    REFERENCES `libreria`.`vendedor` (`nombre`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `apellidos_vendedor`
    FOREIGN KEY (`apellidos_vendedor`)
    REFERENCES `libreria`.`vendedor` (`apellidos`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT);

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Como estas?
En mi experiencia, las claves primarias siempre son enteros autoincrementales. Por eso, el codigo de tu tabla, para evitar futuros problemas tendria que quedar asi:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libreria`.`Vendedor` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nombre` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`apellidos` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`direccion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`telefono` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`salario` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`fecha_contratacion` DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Espero te ayude. Este es un ejemplo de la primera tabla que se esta creando. Sigue lo mismo para las demas